# How to use built-in receipt printer of android device

Tags: android, printing, built-in, android-print-framework

I got a (china based) android based device with **builtin receipt printer**. I can install my app in into it. It has **4.4.4 (Kitkat)** Android version.

A printer testing builtin app also install in the device.I got no SDK with it nor company name defined on device.

I need to built an app that can use its printer. But I don't know how? **No SDK no documentation** comes with it.

It has a mini usb port like any android phone.

Please help me.

Comment: Well I have found solution a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Well I have found solution a solution. Downloaded a open source project which can write on available ports. I sent text to ports one by one. Printer worked while **writing on a specific port**.

But one issue remains. I cannot activate printer (or that port where printer is attached). After opening device default app, it activates printer then my app works.

Comment: So this is coming late. What open source project did you download and how were you able to activate the printer?

Comment: Does anyone have any link to any driver that can be used? I have the same problem

Comment: Thabks for the answer that actually does not help.